# Кастомизировать таблицу grafana

Tags: таблицы, grafana

Необходимо в grafana создать подобную таблицу, данные получаются одной строкой из postgres базы.
Не нашел инструмента где можно было бы задавать названия колонок, добавлять вручную поля. Это возможно? Может как-то с помощью переменных?

[image: Таблица]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такого рода свободную таблицу можно сделать с помощью элемента Text и переменных. Элемент Text поддерживает разметку html.
[image: Например]

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Показатель</td>
            <td>Прогноз</td>
            <td>Факт</td>
            <td>Откл.%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Кол-во строк в заказе</td>
            <td>$StrokPlan</td>
            <td>${StrokFact}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Кол-во строк на сборку итог</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Кол-во строк зона 1</td>
            <td>${Zone1_Plan}</td>
            <td>${Zone1_Fact}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Кол-во строк зона 2</td>
            <td>${Zone2_Plan}</td>
            <td>${Zone2_Fact}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Кол-во строк зона 3</td>
            <td>${Zone3_Plan}</td>
            <td>${Zone3_Fact}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Кол-во пред. пополнения пикинга</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Кол-во пополнения пикинга</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>${test}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```